# Are there mathematical solutions for redistricting?

Tags: geometry, optimization

For a long time, the practice of **gerrymandering** has been a large problem in U.S. politics. It kind of surprises me that there hasn't been an agreed-upon solution to it yet. The three main properties one needs in redistricting are:

1. population equality
2. contiguity
3. compactness

This seems like it could, in theory, be solved as an optimization problem.

How much work has been done on this? Is there a way to express the problem mathematically? If so, what challenges exist that prevent us from having a formulaic approach, so that politics doesn't get in the way of fair redistricting?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gRCZR_BbjTo

Comment: Well to answer your questions. Yes there are density maps that people use create districts. the problem stems from this being a political issue. Sure there are multiple ways for us to redistrict for a more "Balanced" regional districts, but the same density maps can be exploited to also unbalance the system based on how people vote.

Comment: https://sites.tufts.edu/gerrymandr/resources/

Comment: I actually did watch that Vox video a while back. My understanding, though, is that they want to use it to evaluate how "gerrymandered" a given map is, by comparing it to the many possible redistrictings that they generated. But is it infeasible to generate the "best" possible redistricting, finding the one map with highest scores for population equality, contiguity, and compactness?

Comment: You might look at [this artlicle](http://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Ford/Balinski.pdf) by Michel Balinski in the American Mathematical Monthly.

Comment: @Glu it's more like there is a set of best possible maps, and not just one. We can also look at those best possible sets and then measure the density of political affiliation, and thus while the map is equitable compared to those three, it can be exploited to gerrymandering.

Comment: The problem is that population equality, contiguity, and compactness are not the only important features of redistricting.  There are innumerable other variables.  For example, in Arizona has a population of about 7 million.  The Phoenix metropolitan area has a population of almost 5 million.  It would be quite simple to draw district boundaries in Arizona which create compact, contiguous districts which completely eliminate the voting power of anyone living in a rural area.

Comment: However, rural residents make up something like 15-20% of the population, and therefore ought to be represented by at least one (if not two) representatives.  The same problem occurs when considering other interest groups, such as native peoples in Arizona, urban areas which are not Phoenix, minority populations who should have representation, etc.

Comment: In principle, one could enumerate a list of criteria, and seek to optimize with respect to those criteria (at which point, the problem *does* become one of optimization), but I suspect that the reason that districts are not selected algorithmically is that agreeing on the right algorithm is a politically fraught process.  Indeed, I suspect that once the criteria for redistricting are sorted out, the districts are drawn algorithmically.

Answer (score 0):

An upcoming workshop:

- [Geometry of Redistricting Summer School](https://sites.tufts.edu/gerrymandr/), Tufts University, August 7-11, 2017.

An ongoing project:

- [Quantifying Gerrymandering](https://services.math.duke.edu/projects/gerrymandering/), Duke University.

Some recent articles:

- Erica Klarreich, [How to quantify (and fight) gerrymandering](https://www.quantamagazine.org/the-mathematics-behind-gerrymandering-20170404/), Quanta Magazine, April 4, 2017.
- Shannon Najmabadi, [Meet the math professor who’s fighting gerrymandering with geometry](http://www.chronicle.com/article/Meet-the-Math-Professor/239260), The Chronicle of Higher Education, February 22, 2017.

---

[political-science](/questions/tagged/political-science) [gerrymandering](/questions/tagged/gerrymandering)